# retain radio button value on page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I know there are similar posts on this topic but i didn't find my answer from there.

An online MCQ  exam test. Number of  questions in the page is variable. 
4 options for every MCQ(multiple choice question).

```
<input type="radio"  name="my"  value="1"/>

<input type="radio"  name="my"  value="2"/>

<input type="radio"  name="my" value="3"/>

<input type="radio"  name="my" value="4"/>
```

Examniee has to select one for each question. On page refresh, deselection takes place. How to retain the checked values on refresh - javascript, jquery or what? Details necessary.
Scripting language is php.

Answer (score 0):

Basic html:

```
<input type="radio" name="my" selected="selected" value="1" />
```

via PHP:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $sel = ($i == $some_way_to_tell_which_to_select) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo <<<EOL
<input type="radio" name="my"$sel value="$i" />

EOL;
}
```

Comment: $MArc, So you want to say that 'Basic html' will be executed on visiting the page for the first time, else the 'via PHP' part should be executed on further visits through refresh or pressing the Enter key over the address bar?  Can u make any suggestion about the $some_way_to_tell_which_to_select?

Comment: No, basic html shows you make a radio button appear "selected". The php version shows howyou'd generate the four radio buttons and select whichever one the user had chosen originally.

Comment: can't find any way with $some_way_to_tell_which_to_select

Comment: waiting for some reply from you

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want an auto save form's data feature. There are several jquery plugins for this. Recently I used: 
http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/autosave/

Only javascript can give you this kind of functionality with data still not parsed in the server side.

Comment: $NomikOS, how to use that in my purpose?

Comment: @istiaque-ahmed It is a jquery plugin. Just use it as a normal one. Works the same as a gmail or wordpress autosave feature, ie, if user leaves the page containing a form without submit it all data on it is saved to cookies. So the next time user arrives to that page all form's data will be there. That includes the refresh/reload page action and radio buttons selected. It is sure that will solve your problem. Just try it...

Comment: I tried to go through the page well. they say, values(radio button, text field etc) will be saved. Ok fine.. But on page refresh how will one of the 4 options of the radio buttons  be selected? Which cookie, how to use .. and so on?

Comment: waiting to hear something from you

Comment: @istiaque-ahmed Hi! I did not saw this comment. Please check one of my [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757765/auto-restore-using-jquery-autosave-plug-in] (question). The question includes an `EDIT (with a solution)` that talks about an `autorestore: true` option. Please don forget accept this answer if all goes OK, Thanks!

Comment: But how can I use that in my case? the page has n number of radio button groups..

Comment: the site says "The plug-in requires Klaus Hartl’s jQuery Cookie plug-in to work." But the link to the plug in does not work,